# How to get modifier key event(alt+ctrl+shift),

Tags: winapi, c++11

If anyone is working on win32 API.Please have a look to below issue.
I have a requirement to call a function when modifier keys are pressed(alt+ctrl+shift) at same time in win32 programming.But I am not getting how to handle this event when modifiers keys are pressed at same time.
If someone have any idea please post it.

Comment: Look at [`RegisterHotKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) and the [`WM_HOTKEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279.aspx) window message.

Answer (score 6):

To get the status of key there is an API [`GetKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx). With help of this you can check whether a key is down or up.

For example:

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)& 0x8000)
   //Key is pressed
```

you can also check in combination like this:

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)& 0x8000 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL)& 0x8000)
   //ctrl+shift key is pressed.
```

Comment: It is not clear WHEN would you call your requested function? At what event would you get the state of those keys?

Comment: `(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000)` actually means `SHIFT` key is locked. Don't mix `keypress` and `keydown`.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages, and track the state (up or down) for all of these keys: `VK_SHIFT`, `VK_CONTROL`, `VK_MENU`.